# How to open folder in our gui file like vs code in python tkinter?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a function to get all file in my gui like vs code. I tried many times I have created a function through which I am able to get file of folder in my gui but I am unable to open file from my gui and I am also unable to put image before their names according to what extensions is contain

error:-

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\coding notes\pytho project\project1.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    list_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",lambda event=None:Open(file))
  File "d:\coding notes\pytho project\project1.py", line 6, in Open
    with open(value,"r") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/coding notes/pytho project'
```

this is my code

```
import os
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
def Open(value):
    editor.delete(1.0,END)
    with open(value,"r") as f:
        editor.insert(1.0,f.read())
def Open_folder():
    global file 
    file = askdirectory()
    if file == "":
        file = None
    else:
        for i in os.listdir(file):
            list_box.insert(END,i)
root = Tk()
file = ""
root.geometry("1550x850+0+0")
editor = Text(root,font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",insertbackground="white")
editor.place(x=400,y=0,relwidth=True,height=850)
Button(root,text="Open folder",font="Consolas 10",relief=GROOVE,bg="gray19",fg="white",command=Open_folder).place(x=0,y=0)
list_box = Listbox(root,font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",selectbackground="gray29")
list_box.place(x=0,y=20,width=400,height=850)
list_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",lambda event=None:Open(file))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You open the selected folder instead of the selected file in the listbox inside `Open()`. If you want to show an image before the filename, you need to use `ttk.Treeview` instead of `Listbox`.

Comment: `listdir` gives only filename but you need full path to open it - `folder/file`. So you have to keep in global variable name of selected folder and later add it to filename when you open it.

Comment: what means `unable`? if you get error message then show it in question (not in comments). Don't expect that we will run code to see errors. And code may work correctly on our computers. And we can't read in your mind - so you have to add all details in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the *selected folder* instead of the *selected file in the listbox* inside `Open()`.  You need to get the selected file from the listbox and join the selected folder to get the full filepath:

```py
def Open(value):
    # get the selected filename from listbox
    file = list_box.get(list_box.curselection())
    # get the absolute path of the selected filename
    filepath = os.path.join(value, file)
    
    editor.delete(1.0, END)
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        editor.insert(1.0, f.read())
```